# Excel File Directory Transfer

Tags: vba, excel

Question on how I can transfer a specific files to a specific directory.

Basically, these are images that have unique file names and will be transferred to a assigned directory and I want to accomplish it using Excel.

So in `A1` is the image file location and `B1` is the location where we will transfer the file.

Ex.

- `A1` = `J:\folder1\`  ,`B1` = `J:\folder2\`
- `A2` = is the file name *image.jpg* `B2` = is the location where I want to put *image.jpg*

  for example, i want to copy `J:\folder1\image.jpg` to `J:\folder2\location1\`

Comment: I want to help, but isn't clear. You said `B1` and `B2` have same info? `"B1 is the location where we will transfer the file."` and latter `"B2 = is the location where I want to put image.jpg"`. Where is destination file name? is the same name in `A2`?

Answer (score 1):

-Use the appropriate methods in `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. 
To get you started, you'll need to include:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Then you could use

```
fso.CopyFile(source, destination[, overwrite] )
```

Where source and destination are the **full names** (including paths) of the file.

-Simpler but with less options(no overwrite option)

```
Dim SourceFile, DestinationFile As String
SourceFile = "SRCFILE"   ' Define source file name.
DestinationFile = "DESTFILE"   ' Define target file name.
FileCopy(SourceFile, DestinationFile)   ' Copy source to target.
```

Comment: Thia is more worthy of a comment than an answer.

Comment: `Dim sourceFile As String, DesintationFile As String` otherwise `SourceFile` is implicitly type Variant. It may not matter in this case, but it's a good habit declare variables of specific type especially when that type is known in advance.

Comment: ill give this a try, i'm am not so familiar to this stuff so cross fingers to me.

Comment: @user3488498 Did it work for you? Could you formally accept this answer?

Comment: I really want to figure this out but the type of approach that was suggested is beyond my scope of knowledge to make it work. I am reluctant to say that it did not work for me, but if someone out there can figure it out; I'm sure many will benefit this idea and I should give a thanks to you for doing this effort.